# How to confirm that Deleting an object from S3 Amazon actually worked / deleted?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to check whether an object was deleted from Amazon S3. In my test scenario, i know the object doesn't exist because I'm trying to delete a file with a random Guid filename.

[image]

When I delete the file, I get back the a similar response as to when I delete a file from S3 which *does* exist.

here's a response when I delete an existing file:

[image]

here's a response when I attempt to delete a file that doesn't exist:

[image]

So i'm not too sure how to check this :(

Side note (or a potential clue?) - this bucket has VERSIONING turned on / active.  I *think* this used to work on the bucket when versioning was off and the `HttpStatusCode` was something else when the file didn't exist when attempting a delete.

Also - before people suggest this - Yes, i know I can do this in TWO steps (delete, then check if exists) but this is now TWO round trips and I'm *really* hoping I don't need to do that as it feels like the 2nd call is a waste.

Comment: You will never known if it is deleted, because it is up to S3 cloud if, when and how it is deleted. You can only check if the S3 cloud will return a deleted response if you request a deleted file. So you have to trust the S3 cloud. And if you do that then you can also trust the response from the delete request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s important to understand that Amazon S3 provides eventual consistency for DELETES in all AWS Regions. Additionally, Amazon S3 replicates data across multiple servers in your chosen AWS Region. This means that when you delete an object, it can take some time for the deletion to replicate across all the servers. You might see that if you try to read an object immediately after deleting it, then Amazon S3 returns the object.

You can use one of the following ways to confirm that the object is in the process of deletion:

- Enable the debug option on the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI). Then, run the head-object command using the AWS CLI. If the response from a head-object command includes a DeleteMarker header, then this means that the object was deleted. If the response doesn't include a DeleteMarker header, then the object wasn't deleted.
- Use an AWS SDK to send a HeadObject API call. If the x-amz-delete-marker field in the response is true, then the object was deleted. If x-amz-delete-marker is false, then the object wasn't deleted.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-listing-deleted-objects/

Comment: `x-amz-delete-marker` <-- is that value the same as the `deleteMarker` property in both of my images, above?

Comment: Also - I was thinking why eventual consistency would work in this case. I know what EC is .. but in this case, there is no file, so there's nothing to delete. So I would have though an exception is thrown or at least a 404 or something. I _guess_ what this means is: "Ok - you want to delete a file? no problems, i'll _try_ and do this 'later on' [That's the EC bit]. So thanks for the _request_ to delete a file."

Comment: Regarding the `deleteMarker`: Yes, I believe that this is the same.

Comment: Regarding eventual consistency: In this case that's not an "I'll try and do this later on". It's just the fact that Amazon S3 stores multiple replicas of your object across multiple Availability Zones and it takes some time for all replicas to be deleted.

Comment: Regarding when there's no object to delete in the first place: I'm not an expert on the inner workings of Amazon S3, so I can only speculate. Systems are often designed in a way that the intent of an action (here: Delete an object) drives the response (here: You want the object to be deleted? Well, it may have been deleted earlier, or maybe it never existed, but it certainly is deleted now). Similar to a DVD-Player: If you press the STOP button it will stop the video. And if it wasn't playing in the first place, it will not throw an error. The intend was to stop the video, and it's stopped.

Comment: Of course, one can argue that in some use-cases it may have semantic relevance whether the S3 object has been there and now it has been deleted, as opposed to it never having existed. If this is your use case, there might be indicators from S3 that I'm not aware of. But if that's import to you, you always can maintain an object index of your own, e.g. processing S3 events into Amazon DynamoDB.